# Adding Remote Dev to a Facebook Flux Store Application, Help Listing out the Action Creators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

https://www.npmjs.com/package/remotedev
I'm trying to add remotedev tools extension to an legacy react project that is using Facebook flux;
It shows to be connected but every time it doesn't show action creators. only the word change

Here is the store code below.

```
import { connectViaExtension, extractState } from 'remotedev';

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var Base = require('backbone-extend-node');
var remotedev = connectViaExtension();


/**
 * Abstract store implementation, this class has two goals:
 * - Implements handlers for dispatcher actions
 * - Registers change events
 *
 * @abstract
 */

// Initial state is {}
remotedev = connectViaExtension();
// Subscribe to remotedev


remotedev.init({}, { name: 'Facebook Flux' });
// Subscribe to RemoteDev

export var AbstractStore = Base.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    this.emitter = this.buildEmitter();
    this.assignAllHandlers();
    remotedev.sub
  },

  /**
   * Actuall magic responsible for assigning all handlers to corresponding dispatcher actions
   */
  assignAllHandlers: function() {
    var actionHandlers = this.getActionHandlers();
    dispatcher.register(function(action) {
      if (actionHandlers[action.actionType]) {
        remotedev.send(actionHandlers[action.actionType]);
        actionHandlers[action.actionType].call(this, action.payload);
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },

  /**
   * This is not in const as we use this for testing
   * @access private
   * @visibleForTesting
   */
  getChangeEvent: function() {
    return 'change';
  },

  /**
   * We should seperate it for easy testing
   * @access private
   * @visibleForTesting
   */
  buildEmitter: function() {
    var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    eventEmitter.setMaxListeners(0);

    return eventEmitter;
  },

  emitChange: function() {
    this.emitter.emit(this.getChangeEvent(), this);
  },

  addChangeListener: function(listener) {
    this.emitter.on(this.getChangeEvent(), listener);
  },

  /**
  * It's essential to remove listeners to prevent memory leaks
  */
  removeChangeListener: function(listener) {
    this.emitter.removeListener(this.getChangeEvent(), listener);
  },

  removeAllListeners: function() {
    this.emitter.removeAllListeners(this.getChangeEvent());
  }
});


// reducers
```

Picture Below of what is show so far

[Redux Dev Tools Only Showing Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8JZm.png)

Trying to show action creators instead of the word "update"